# remove every 4 rows between two numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

for example, I have a data frame with one column containing numbers. these is how it looks.

```
head(c1)
    c
1 300
2 302
3 304
4 306
5 308
6 310
```

Here is the sample data frame.

```
c1 <- structure(list(c = c(300, 302, 304, 306, 308, 310, 312, 314, 
    316, 318, 320, 322, 324, 326, 328, 330, 332, 334, 336, 338, 340, 
    342, 344, 346, 348, 350, 352, 354, 356, 358, 360, 362, 364, 366, 
    368, 370, 372, 374, 376, 378, 380, 382, 384, 386, 388, 390, 392, 
    394, 396, 398, 400)), .Names = "c", row.names = c(NA, -51L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to delete the rows between 300 to 310 and 310 to 320 and so on..
 I want to have a dataframe like these

```
300
310
320
330
340
350
.
.
.
400
```

Any ideas how to do these, I found how to remove every nth row, but not every four rows between two numbers

Comment: It seems that `c1[seq(1, NROW(c1), 5),]` does the trick.

Comment: `c1[c1$c %% 10 == 0, ]` or `c1[c1$c %% 10 == 0, , drop=FALSE]` if you want to keep it as a data.frame with 1 column?

Comment: Does my suggestion work for you? i.e. do you want to keep only multiples of 10 or is you real problem different and you need to actually submit every every rows regardless of their numbers?

Comment: @docendodiscimus: No no... your suggestion worked for my problem..

Comment: these is what excatly i am looking for ....thank you @ docendodiscimus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the modulo operator `%%`. If you want the result as an atomic vector, you can run

```
c1$c[c1$c %% 10 == 0]
```

or if you want it as a `data.frame` with 1 column, you can use

```
c1[c1$c %% 10 == 0, , drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: Side note: this solution only works for multiple of 10. Not if the values every 5 rows in c$c1 are not.

Comment: @Pascal, correct, but it seemed the most direct approach to me for the specific example

Comment: @Pascal: thank you very much.. I tried both the the suggestions from you and from docendo discimus...and both worked